# How to formulate and analyze systems of stochastic differential equations?

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I'm having trouble finding reference material on how to deal with systems of stochastic differential equations. Specifically, I'm interested in ecological models.

For example, consider the standard Lotka-Volterra predator-prey equations:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{dx}{dt}&=rx-\gamma xy \\ 
\frac{dy}{dt}&=\alpha xy-my.
\end{aligned}
$$

I'd like to study stochastic versions of this and similar models. Something like:

$$
\begin{aligned}
dX&=(rX-\gamma XY)dt+c_1XdB \\ 
dY&=(\alpha XY-mY)dt+c_2YdB.
\end{aligned}
$$

Is the above SDE system sensible/tractable? I'm sure basic stochastic predator-prey models have been beat to death already, but I just can't find them (or my inability to understand them may be the issue).

Any insight, hints, or references is appreciated. Right now I'm reading *Stochastic Differential Equations* by Bernt Øksendal (in chapter 3 so far). Will this text give me what I need, or are there other texts that will help with systems such as the above?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in the articles "Stochastic prey-predator system with foraging arena scheme" and  "Study on Dynamic Behavior of a Stochastic Predator–Prey System with Beddington–DeAngelis Functional Response and Regime Switching." they study a generalization that contains the above
[image]